# Quartz Scheduler Weekly schedule with repeat count and Weekdays or Random days

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am implementing Quartz scheduler for my webapplication.
  I have to schedule weekly on monday,tuesday repeat 3weeks

Two ways in Quartz Scheduler,

1)simple Trigger:

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
.withIdentity("trigger1","group1")
.startAt(runTime)
.withSchedule(weeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(DateBuilder.MONDAY,10,10))            
.build();
```

Here i can mention only one weekday in weeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute method,I couldnt mention multiple weekdays

2)Cron Trigger:

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
.withIdentity("trigger1","group1")
.startAt(runTime)           
.withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 10 15 ? * MON-FRI"))          
.build()
```

Here i couldnt mention repeat count or repeat interval

Please guide me in right direction. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5):

Did you try :

```
newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1").startAt(runTime)  
               .withSchedule(DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.dailyTimeIntervalSchedule().onDaysOfTheWeek(2, 3).withRepeatCount(2)).build();
```